# Cannot focus (click into) html input elements

Tags: html, css, input

TL;DR click the link

My input elements are on strike and refuse to work.  I've stripped this down to isolate the variables, and I've found a few things that fix the problem, but I know there's something else going on here...

http://jsfiddle.net/9PkYG/2/

HTML and CSS per SO guidelines:

```
<div class="fl half">
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <input />
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <input />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="fr half">
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <input />
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <input />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="input-wrap">
    <select>
        <option>Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fl { float: left; }
.fr { float: right; }

.half { width: 50%; }

input { border: 1px solid black; }

.input-wrap { margin-bottom: 14px; position: relative; }

.clear { clear: both; }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .input-wrap div is overlapping the inputs. SO, when you click on the inputs, you are actually clicking .input-wrap which is over them.

The reason is that the .half divs that contain the inputs are floating.
Easy fix would be to add style `clear:both` on you existing css add class 'clear' to .input-wrap div.

```
<div class="input-wrap clear">
    <select>
        <option>Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/mafUh/1/

Comment: ahh! I see.. it was the bottom div overlapping the top. Musa had the right idea, but there are many .input-wraps and i didn't see that it was the bottom one covering the top (because of a float clearing issue)

Answer (score 3):

Adding `position: relative; z-index: 1;` to the `input {}` rule seemed to work, thanks to Musa's suggestion.

http://jsfiddle.net/9PkYG/4/

However, this doesn't seem like the best solution, can you not have input elements inside position: relative???

Ignoring this solution, I'm still looking for a better answer.  This seems like a bug...  Why would removing the select element, or removing the floats, effect the z-index of the inputs/wrap?

Answer (score 1):

Your div .input-wrap is over the input, removing position: relative seems to put it behind the inputs.

```
.input-wrap { margin-bottom: 14px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9PkYG/3/

Comment: but i need the pos: rel; so I can pos: abs something else inside of the input-wrap

Comment: Why don't you put the inputs into that div?

Answer (score 0):

In relation to the question: it is also worth noting that if you are trying to `focus` on a not-natively focusable element, you can try to use the html attribute `tabindex` to make it focusable.